# Who composed this cadenza from Mozart Piano Concerto No. 20?

Tags: mozart, cadenza

The cadenza of the 3rd movement from this video (starts at minute 29:07) seems really short compared to the version composed by Beethoven I usually listen to.

I've seen the same version in a recording by Murray Perahia (starts at minute 29:27):

I personally like this version a lot and I want to know who the composer is.

Who composed this version of cadenza? Murray Perahia?

Comment: Hi! Questions identifying pieces aren't [on topic here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but you can ask in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room)